# How do I call an GUI function from Main class in Python?

Tags: python, user-interface, progress-bar, call

I need `ProgressBar` widget in my_app ,When I click on the `pushButton`, I can not call `def call_progressBar2(self,value1)` in `def download (self)`.
Can anyone help me?

main.py

```
from g import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys
import time
from b import classb

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        instance_b=classb()
        tvt= self.call_progressBar2(self)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.pushButton1, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), \
                       lambda: instance_b.download(tvt))## I need  help here.


    def call_progressBar2(self,value1): 
        while True:
            time.sleep(0.05)
            value = self.ui.progressBar.value() + 1
            self.ui.progressBar.setValue(value)
            QtGui.qApp.processEvents()
            if (not self.ui._active or
                value >= self.progressBar.maximum()):
                if value==value1:
                    break
        self.ui._active = False            

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MainWindow()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

b.py

```
import time
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class classb (object):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
       self.parent=parent

#I need call def call_progressBar2() here.
    def download(self):
       from main import MainWindow 
       instance_m= MainWindow
       print 'a'
       instance_m.call_progressBar2(20)
       print 'b'
       instance_m.call_progressBar2(40)
       print 'c'
       instance_m.call_progressBar2(60)
       print 'd'
       instance_m.call_progressBar2(100)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating instance of `MainWindow` in `classb.download` method, just pass it as parameter when you connect the signal, this way:

```
#tvt= self.call_progressBar2(self) #No need for tvt
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.pushButton1, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), \
                       lambda: instance_b.download(self)) #self here is the MainWindow Instance
```

Then in `classb.download` method:

```
def download(self, main_window):
    print 'a'
    main_window.call_progressBar2(20)
    print 'b'
    main_window.call_progressBar2(40)
    print 'c'
    main_window.call_progressBar2(60)
    print 'd'
    main_window.call_progressBar2(100)
```

Comment: Can you help me ? here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34967007/how-can-i-make-new-thread-in-python

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just pass the current `MainWindow` instance to your `download` function when you connect the signal ? Or just pass it to `classb` initialiser when you instanciate it just before you connect the signal ? Or specify `download` so it takes a callback, and pass the `MainWindow` current instance's `call_progressBar2` method as callback when you connect the signal ?

Comment: I want to use (  def call_progressBar2) as multi-function in the program, so I need to call it in class_b now.

Comment: @JehanMazen I don't understand what you mean by "using call_progressBar2 as multi-function". But anyway: if `classb.download` needs to access the `call_progressBar2` method of the calling `MainWindow` instance, you have to pass either the calling  `MainWindow` instance OR it's `call_progressBar` method (remember that in Python functions and methods are objects too) to `download` one way or another. I mentioned the three most obvious ways to do so, pick the one that suits you.

Comment: Thank you for your comments and suggestions